# SVN: fix or remove broken revisions

Tags: svn

How to fix or remove broken revisions in SVN?

For example we have repository with 1000 revisions and revisions from 100 to 200 is broken. I don't really care about that revisions, so they can be removed if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here solution if you don't have backup and you don't care about broken revisions.

First of all you need to backup one by one all revisions, then create new rep and import in it all that backups

Here two scripts

First to for backup

```sh
#!/bin/bash

svn="/var/lib/svn/repository_name"
dir="/some/dir/for/backup"

svnadmin dump $svn -r1 > $dir/r1.dump

for rev in `seq 2 1000`; do # 1000 - it's number of last revision
  echo $rev
  svnadmin dump $svn -r$rev --incremental > $dir/r${rev}.dump
done
```

And script for import

```sh
#!/bin/bash

svn="/var/lib/svn/new_repository_name" 
dir="/some/dir/for/backup"

svnadmin create $svn
svnadmin load $svn --ignore-uuid < $dir/r1.dump
for rev in `seq 2 1000`; do 
  echo $rev
  svnadmin load $svn < $dir/r${rev}.dump
done
```

Comment: It's worth noting that everyone who has checked out a working copy from this repository will need to throw that out & start fresh.